# Really Blank Activity

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

Firstly thanks to Mark Murphy, regarding comment 10 and the link to a really blank activity template in [Android Issue 67513](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67513)

Now the question regarding the new template: *Is it intended that it should still create a new appcompat_v7_n+1 library project?*

When I tried it, one was created. I deleted it, removed the reference from the blank activity project, then had to delete references to appcompat styles in the values folders and a style in the manifest.

Don't get me wrong, doing that was no big deal and it's a vast improvement but I'm wondering if that was intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it intended that it should still create a new appcompat_v7_n+1 library project?

Crap.

The new-project wizard adds some of that. I thought it was all in the new-activity wizard, which *also* adds some of that when using the stock templates.

I'll need to fork the `NewAndroidApplication` template to get rid of those bits. I'll work on that. I've added a note to [the project `README`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-rba) in the interim.

Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. Is still useful as it stands though. Thanks once again.